# Java Swing keyEvent vs keyPressed/keyReleased - different key codes?

Tags: java, swing, events

Why does keyTyped return different KeyEvents to keyPressed/keyReleased?

```
package poke;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PokeEvents implements KeyListener {
    static public void main(String args[]) {
        new PokeEvents();
    }

    public PokeEvents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.err.println("keyTyped: "+e.getKeyCode()+", "+e.getKeyChar()+", "+e.getExtendedKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.err.println("keyPressed: "+e.getKeyCode()+", "+e.getKeyChar()+", "+e.getExtendedKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.err.println("keyReleased: "+e.getKeyCode()+", "+e.getKeyChar()+", "+e.getExtendedKeyCode());
    }

}
```

Run it, press 'a' on the keyboard, output is:

```
keyPressed: 65, a, 65
keyTyped: 0, a, 0
keyReleased: 65, a, 65
```

OK, seems harmless enough, you say. Let's up the ante. Try combining it with Ctrl (the original bug in our software that exposed this was dealing with Ctrl-key combinations).

```
keyPressed: 17, , 17
keyPressed: 65, , 65
keyTyped: 0, , 0
keyReleased: 65, , 65
keyReleased: 17, , 17
```

Just to note: 17 - control, 65 - a.

On `keyTyped` there is no way to know what the character is. It seems to be a `null` character of sorts.

Since the character is not rendering in the browser, here it is as per the editor and in Eclipse:

[image: output as pasted in the SO editer]

[image: Output as seen in Eclipse console]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no different key codes. With and without `Ctrl`, The key code generated by the "A" key is 65. What differs when `Ctrl` is pressed is the character that you get from `getKeyChar()`. As it should.

And no, the character that you get is not "a `null` character of sorts", it is the `Ctrl+A` character, with ascii code 1, and it is unprintable.  But it is there.  You just don't see it, because it is, uhm, well, unprintable.

`KeyTyped` always reports 0 for the key code, whether `Ctrl` is pressed or not. The `keyCode` member of the `KeyEvent` class is undefined for the `KeyTyped` event. They are just reusing the same event class, so the getter is still there for you to call, but you are not supposed to, because you are never going to get `keyCode` information when the event is `KeyTyped`. If you want a `keyCode`, look at the `keyPressed` event. If you want a character, look at either the `keyPressed` or the `keyTyped` events.

Comment: This doesn't qualify as an answer to the original question. Why are the keyCodes different, even for a basic 'a' character?

Comment: There are no different keycodes.  The keycode is 65, which is the keycode of the "A" key.  What differs is the character.  As it should.  If you hold down  `Ctrl` and press `A`, you get the `Ctrl+A` character.

Comment: "With and without Ctrl, The key code generated by the "A" key is 65."

Demonstrably not true. Have you seen the output?

Comment: It differs for `keyTyped` which reports `0` for the key code.

Comment: Perhaps what is confusing you is that the event is called `keyTyped` while in fact it should be called `charTyped`.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on that. Now it makes a bit more sense.